# Can this quantity be expressed as $x\cdot \zeta(k)+y, x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

For each natural number $a$ consider the sequence $l(a):=\left(\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}\right)_{b \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Then I have computed that for $k\ge 2, k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p$ prime, we have:

$$|l(1)|_k^k = \zeta(k)-1$$

$$|l(p)|_k^k = \frac{2 p^k-1}{p^k}\zeta(k)-\left(1+\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{j^k}\right)$$

I have also computed for $n=4$ that:

$$|l(4)|_k^k = \zeta(k)\left(3-\frac{1}{4^k}-\frac{2}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\right)-3-\frac{1}{3^k}$$

My question is, if $|l(a)|_k^k = x \zeta(k) + y$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Furthermore:

$$\langle l(1),l(2)\rangle = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{3k+1}{2k(k+1)(2k+1)}$$

Is this last quantity equal to $\log(2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and yes.

1) We have

$$|l(a)|_k^k=\sum_{d\mid a}\left(\prod_{p\mid d}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{p^k}\right)\right)\left(\zeta(k)-\sum_{j=1}^{a/d}\dfrac{1}{j^k}\right)\;,$$
which checks with your special cases.

2) Expand into partial fractions.

P.S. The coefficient of $\zeta(k)$ is equal to
$$\prod_{p^v\Vert a}\left(v+1-\dfrac{v}{p^k}\right)\;,$$
for instance $3-2/2^k$ for $a=4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we consider $|L(a)|_k^k=\sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \frac{(a,b)^k}{b^k}$. It is easy to see that $|l(a)|_k^k=|L(a)|_k^k-y$, where $y=y(a)=\sum_{b=1}^a \frac{(a,b)^k}{b^k}$. Also 
$$|L(a)|_k^k=\sum_{d|a, d<a} \sum_{(b',d)=1} \frac{1}{b'^k}+\zeta(k)=x\zeta(k),$$
where $x=x(a)=\sum_{d|a, d<a} \sum_{d'|d} \frac{\mu(d')}{d'^k}+1.$

PS Also if $a=p_1^{s_1}\dots p_n^{s_n}$ then $x=\prod_{j=1}^n (s_j+1-s_j/p_j^k).$

Comment: Thanks for your answer